# Can "raise a point" and "make a point" mean the same thing generally?

Tags: idioms, dialects

I personally think "to raise a point" means "to mention some point of interest" while "to make a point" means "to state or demonstrate something of particular interest" but I'm in a conversation with someone insisting both mean the latter to them.

Which non-American English dialects (or possibly even regional American dialects) abide by this other person's usage of those two idioms?

Comment: Too bad this is opinion-based, because I have an opinion (-: Raising a point just introduces the point into the conversation. Making a point involves an attempt to convince others of its validity.

Comment: Your perception is the same as mine; your conversational partner hasn't ever given much thought to language, it appears. Let alone metaphors for it.

Comment: If it was just a *hint*, it could even be *dropped* instead of *raised*. That's "English as she is spoke" for ya.